# How can we add throughput (and more) to the output of the jmeter command-line non-GUI mode?

Tags: jmeter

I am running the jmeter via command-line in non-GUI mode.

In the GUI mode, on the summary listener report - there is column for Throughput, etc.

How can I add Throughput (and more) to the output of the jlt file when running jmeter via command-line in non-GUI mode?

Also, does the output of the jlt file depend on the presence of listeners in the jmx file?

Answer (score 0):

Jtl file holds the raw data without summary outputs as Throughput

When viewing jtl with specific listeners it can sum and make average/total of results based on time/count

Comment: What is the process to add additional output to the jlt file?

Comment: @variable see https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables

Comment: I cannot find throughput on that link.

Comment: @variable you need to calculate it in flow and save it in JMeter variable

Answer (score 0):

Throughput is being **calculated**, the formula is

```
Throughput = (number of requests) / (total time).
```

See [JMeter Glossary](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html#glossary) for more details

You can use a spreadsheet tool like [MS Excel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Excel) or [LibreOffice Calc](https://www.libreoffice.org/discover/calc/) to calculate the delta between elapsed times of the first and last samplers and divide it by samples count, however more convenient would be going for [JMeterPluginsCMD Command Line Tool](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeterpluginscmd-command-line/) which can generate tables and charts with your load test metrics.

An example command line to generate a CSV-based equivalent of the [Aggregate Report](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Aggregate_Report) listener would be

```
JMeterPluginsCMD.bat --generate-csv AggregateReport.csv --input-jtl /path/to/your/results.jtl --plugin-type AggregateReport
```